# How would I extract a substring from a string and create a new numeric column in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle19c

I have a column (DFI6) where values looks like this and I have a millions of them. I am trying to create a new NUMERIC column with the COD (COD1,COD2....COD5) values.

[IMAGE OF THE TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sZ4K.png)
THIS IS THE WHAT IT SHOULD LOOK LIKE, I HAVE THE FIRST COLUMN AND I AM TRYING TO CREATE 5 NEW ONES

Right now I am at the beginning stage, where I am trying to create individual queries and testing them out, rather than one big nested query.

Sometimes the value for COD5 is a literal "Nothing".  My query to extract COD5

```js
select DFI6,
(case 
    when DFI6 like '%COD5%' THEN
    (case
            when REGEXP_LIKE(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(DFI6, INSTR(DFI6,'COD5=')),6),'[a-z]')
            then '-1'
            else (nvl(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(DFI6, INSTR(DFI6,'COD5=')),6),'-1'))
            end)
    else '-1'
            end)+0 --note: I added zero to turn the column into numeric
             as COD5
    from myTable
where updated_date>sysdate-300
and DFI6 is not null
```

Query to extract COD4 is:

```html
select DFI6,
(case 
    when DFI6 like '%COD4%' 
    THEN
    (case
        when REGEXP_LIKE(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(DFI6, INSTR(DFI6,'COD4=')),6),'[a-z]')
            then '-1'
            else SUBSTR(SUBSTR(DFI6, INSTR(DFI6, 'COD3'), INSTR(DFI6, '|COD4') - INSTR(DFI6, 'COD3')),6)
        end)
    else '-1'
    end)+0 --note: I added zero to turn the column into numeric
        as COD4
    from myTable
where updated_date>sysdate-30
and DFI6 is not null
```

ISSUE:

- Some of the DEF6 columns do not contain a certain COD, and if they don't then -1 should be in the relevant COD sub-column.
- Some of the COD values can be null and if they are then -1 should be in the relevant COD column.
- When I am adding 0 at the end of the case statement the columns are numeric, but I fail to fetch all the rows. But when I don't add zero the column is non-numeric but fetches all the rows. Basically I am loosing 600-900k rows.
- I have tried to wrap the whole case statement into to_number, and it did not work.

I am using SQL navigator6.2.1 oracle DB version [19.16.0.0.0] and some of the new functions do not work with my version. I am very new to SQL and would appreciate any help.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - using just CASE expression and SubStr() function:

```sql
WITH      -- Sample data
    tbl  AS
        (
            Select 'COD1=01YTEFG|COD2=22|COD3=33|COD4=21|COD5=22' "DFI6" From Dual Union All
            Select 'COD1=02YTEFG|COD2=25|COD3=37|COD4=27|COD5=28' "DFI6" From Dual Union All
            Select 'COD1=01YTEFG|COD2=22|COD3=33|COD4=21|COD5=22' "DFI6" From Dual Union All
            Select 'COD1=02YTEFG|COD2=25|COD3=37|COD4=27' "DFI6" From Dual Union All        -- NO COD5
            Select 'COD1=02YTEFG|COD2=253|COD3=37|COD4=27' "DFI6" From Dual Union All        -- NO COD5  AND   COD2 HAS THREE NUMBERS
            Select 'COD1=None|COD2=22|COD3=33|COD4=21|COD5=22' "DFI6" From Dual Union All     -- COD1 = None
            Select 'COD1=02YTEFG|COD5=28' "DFI6" From Dual Union All                          -- NO CODES 2, 3 AND 4
            Select 'COD1=01YTEFG|COD2=22|COD3=33|COD4=21|COD5=22' "DFI6" From Dual Union All
            Select 'COD1=02YTEFG|COD2=25|COD3=37|COD4=27|COD5=Nothing' "DFI6" From Dual 
        )
--
--  Main SQL
SELECT
    DFI6,
    CASE 
        WHEN  INSTR(DFI6, 'COD1=') = 0 OR                                               -- element is not here OR
              INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD1=') + 5, 1)) = 0        -- first char after 'COD1=' is not numeric
        THEN -1   
        --
        WHEN  INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD1=') + 7, 1)) > 0 AND    -- third and
              INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD1=') + 6, 1)) > 0 AND    -- second and
              INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD1=') + 5, 1)) > 0        -- first char after 'COD1=' are all numerics 
        THEN To_Number(SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD1=') + 5, 3))                   -- take all three 
        --
        WHEN  INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD1=') + 6, 1)) > 0 AND    -- second and
              INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD1=') + 5, 1)) > 0        -- first char after 'COD1=' are both numerics
        THEN To_Number(SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD1=') + 5, 2))                   -- take them both 
        --
        WHEN  INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD1=') + 5, 1)) > 0        -- just 1 numeric char after 'COD1='
        THEN To_Number(SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD1=') + 5, 1))                   -- take it
    ELSE -1 END "COD1",                                                     -- ELSE -1
    --          ---------------------------------------------
    CASE 
       WHEN  INSTR(DFI6, 'COD2=') = 0 OR 
              INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD2=') + 5, 1)) = 0
        THEN -1   
        --
        WHEN  INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD2=') + 7, 1)) > 0 AND 
              INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD2=') + 6, 1)) > 0 AND 
              INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD2=') + 5, 1)) > 0
        THEN To_Number(SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD2=') + 5, 3))
        --
        WHEN  INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD2=') + 6, 1)) > 0 AND 
              INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD2=') + 5, 1)) > 0 
        THEN To_Number(SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD2=') + 5, 2))
        --
        WHEN  INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD2=') + 5, 1)) > 0 
        THEN To_Number(SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD2=') + 5, 1))
    ELSE -1 END "COD2",
    --          ---------------------------------------------
    CASE 
       WHEN  INSTR(DFI6, 'COD3=') = 0 OR 
              INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD3=') + 5, 1)) = 0
        THEN -1   
        --
        WHEN  INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD3=') + 7, 1)) > 0 AND 
              INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD3=') + 6, 1)) > 0 AND 
              INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD3=') + 5, 1)) > 0
        THEN To_Number(SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD3=') + 5, 3))
        --
        WHEN  INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD3=') + 6, 1)) > 0 AND 
              INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD3=') + 5, 1)) > 0 
        THEN To_Number(SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD3=') + 5, 2))
        --
        WHEN  INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD3=') + 5, 1)) > 0 
        THEN To_Number(SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD3=') + 5, 1))
    ELSE -1 END "COD3",
    --          ---------------------------------------------
    CASE 
       WHEN  INSTR(DFI6, 'COD4=') = 0 OR 
              INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD4=') + 5, 1)) = 0
        THEN -1   
        --
        WHEN  INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD4=') + 7, 1)) > 0 AND 
              INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD4=') + 6, 1)) > 0 AND 
              INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD4=') + 5, 1)) > 0
        THEN To_Number(SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD4=') + 5, 3))
        --
        WHEN  INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD4=') + 6, 1)) > 0 AND 
              INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD4=') + 5, 1)) > 0 
        THEN To_Number(SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD4=') + 5, 2))
        --
        WHEN  INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD4=') + 5, 1)) > 0 
        THEN To_Number(SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD4=') + 5, 1))
    ELSE -1 END "COD4",
    --          ---------------------------------------------
    CASE 
       WHEN  INSTR(DFI6, 'COD5=') = 0 OR 
              INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD5=') + 5, 1)) = 0
        THEN -1   
        --
        WHEN  INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD5=') + 7, 1)) > 0 AND 
              INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD5=') + 6, 1)) > 0 AND 
              INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD5=') + 5, 1)) > 0
        THEN To_Number(SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD5=') + 5, 3))
        --
        WHEN  INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD5=') + 6, 1)) > 0 AND 
              INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD5=') + 5, 1)) > 0 
        THEN To_Number(SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD5=') + 5, 2))
        --
        WHEN  INSTR('0123456789', SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD5=') + 5, 1)) > 0 
        THEN To_Number(SubStr(DFI6, InStr(DFI6, 'COD5=') + 5, 1))
    ELSE -1 END "COD5"
FROM tbl
--
/*    R e s u l t :
DFI6                                                    COD1       COD2       COD3       COD4       COD5
------------------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
COD1=01YTEFG|COD2=22|COD3=33|COD4=21|COD5=22               1         22         33         21         22 
COD1=02YTEFG|COD2=25|COD3=37|COD4=27|COD5=28               2         25         37         27         28 
COD1=01YTEFG|COD2=22|COD3=33|COD4=21|COD5=22               1         22         33         21         22 
COD1=02YTEFG|COD2=25|COD3=37|COD4=27                       2         25         37         27         -1 
COD1=02YTEFG|COD2=253|COD3=37|COD4=27                      2        253         37         27         -1 
COD1=None|COD2=22|COD3=33|COD4=21|COD5=22                 -1         22         33         21         22 
COD1=02YTEFG|COD5=28                                       2         -1         -1         -1         28 
COD1=01YTEFG|COD2=22|COD3=33|COD4=21|COD5=22               1         22         33         21         22 
COD1=02YTEFG|COD2=25|COD3=37|COD4=27|COD5=Nothing          2         25         37         27         -1
*/
```

Comment: this works great! some of the COD values are 3 digits and some DFI6 do not contain COD5. How should I tackle that?  
should I wrap the case statements into another case statements with 'like' operator to put -1 for the DEF6 that do not contain the certain COD

Comment: @halfjain you can use OR operator within WHEN part of CASE expression to test 2nd and 3rd character after equal sign if it is a numeric or not. I tested just the first after equal sign, If COD5 isn't there at all the -1 should be returned. And -YES- you can have nested CASE expressions.

Comment: Awesome, you think I can look at your test script for reference.

Comment: @halfjain Consider it your code now. You are wellcome to use it any way you want...

Comment: you've been a great resource. thank you for your help!

Comment: @halfjain one important note - case works sequentialy meaning that first condition satisfied wil return the value and exit case. It is crucial to have that in mind when creating multiple WHEN parts. First true and its over....

Comment: hey @d r, i tried the OR operator, I was not able to make it work. So I used multiple When statements inside a case, it catches some but misses some as well. Do you still happen to have the query you ran yesterday with OR operator?

Comment: @halfjain I will do it. Just let me an hour or two and I will edit the answer.

Comment: @halfjain I posted the update - now all your exceptions should be covered. Comments are in the script beside COD1 column. It is all the same for the others.

Comment: this is a work of art. Thank you so much!